# Integral equation solution

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals

I have an integral equations of the form

$ \int s R(s) =s f(s)-\int f(s)ds \tag 1$

Can we solve this integral equation for $f(s)$ interms of  $s,R(s)$ ? Means $R(s)=\psi(s,R(s))$ (with out integral equation symbols, a closed form )

$R(s)= -\frac{1}{4}(e^{-is}-e^{is})^2e^{\frac{4i(e^{-is}-e^{is})}{(e^{-is}+e^{is})^2}}  \tag2$ where i is imaginary notation

Comment: If I differentiate that with respect to $s$, then this just gives $s R(s)=(sf'(s)+f(s))-f(s)=sf'(s)\implies f'(s)=R(s)\implies f(s)=\int R(s)\,ds$. Which seems too easy...

Comment: Actually integrating $R(s)$ is very tough. I know this solution. So I thought to come up with out integral equations). Let me add R(s) now for further clarity

Comment: @Semiclassical Please check my edited version

Comment: That's a good deal harder, yes, and I don't really see why going to the integral equation should be any easier...

Comment: @Semiclassical I came to Integral equation as the last resort coz I couldnt integrate equation (2)[link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934853/integration-using-exponent?noredirect=1#comment1928865_934853). It as actually a trig expression I just converted it in to imaginary terms